# LG TV Control through serial using Windows service runs about 30 seconds after PC is powered on - how to start the service sooner?

Tags: c++, service, serial-port, usb, television

I have created a Windows service that turns an LG TV on/off over a USB-Serial cable when the PC powers on, resumes, or is shutdown or suspended.

The problem is that it currently takes about 30 seconds from when the PC is turned on for my service to actually start and send the appropriate command over the serial port to turn on the TV. By this time, the Windows login is already being displayed.

Is there any way to make Windows start my service sooner, say just after the USB-Serial port driver has been started? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be as simple as changing its name.  Microsoft has a lengthy list of rules that govern what is loaded and in what order.  But oddly, within a particular load group, they are loaded **alphabetically** of all things...
[Microsoft technet social -- load documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/445ddb5e-16b4-4dca-ab89-c0d0ec728af5/boot-order-of-windows-services?forum=winservergen)  That's an old page but most of the rules still apply.

Get ready to tinker with the registry.  Make a backup first! :)